# Silverlight DataGridTextColumn Binding Visibility

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, visibility

Following my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980560/silverlight-datagrid-adding-columns-at-runtime) I am now trying now to bind the visibility of DataGridColumns to a VM notification property. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.visibility(VS.95).aspx) suggests I should be able to do this with ease.

I already have a value convertor and VM notification property that I **know** works (I have tested these on another element on my page:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkAllTeams" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Path=AllTeams}"/>
```

This checkbox control visibility reacts as I would expect. When I set the same binding on the DataTextColumn I get an AG_E_BAD_PARSER error on the *Visibility=* line of XAML:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn 
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Path=AllTeams}"
/>
```

Any ideas anyone?
Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visibility on the DataGridTextColumn is a different beast on the checkbox.  Basically, it isn't a dependency property and can't be data-bound.  If you need this functionality, you can subclass DataGridTextColumn and add your own dependency property to get the behavior.

- Rectangle gets its Visibility property from UIElement and is a dependency property
- DataGridTextColumn gets its Visibility from DataGridColumn and isn't a dependency property.

Comment: Ah this is what I expected :-( Is that an easy task to subclass the DataGridTextColumn? Do you know of any online example for that? Mark

Comment: I don't know of any particular examples for DataGridTextColumn.  The general approach would be to subclass, add a new dependency property for visibility and then use the new subclass in the Datagrid.Columns .  Jesse has a good explanation of dependency properties: http://silverlight.net/blogs/jesseliberty/archive/2008/09/30/dependency-property-system-deeper-dive-part-1.aspx

Comment: That link is dead now, this is the new one: http://jesseliberty.com/2008/09/30/dependency-property-system-%E2%80%93-deeper-dive-part-1/

Comment: how about using an attached property instead?

Answer (score -1):

Did you set BoolToVisibilityConverter as a resource?

Comment: Yep. Previous example on the checkbox proves that.

Comment: actually your example only shows half the code... anyway, as others have said that might not be your problem.

    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"  />
    </Grid.Resources>

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to use a datatemplate:

<DataTemplate x:Key="cBDT">
 <(UIELEMENT HERE) x:Name="chkAllTeams" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Path=AllTeams}"/>
</DataTemplate>

As was mentioned before, only UIElement has the "Visibility" dependency property.

To see an example of this in context:

http://blogs.msdn.com/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx

Comment: Not a good answer - this hides the *element* in the column, not the *column* itself.