# Using the parent's DataContext for Visibility property

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a ViewModel's property of type ObservableCollection. Inside DataGrid I have several DataGridTextColumns bound to item of the ObservableCollection. I need to access parent DataContext (ViewModel) to set Visibility property of one of the DataGridTextColumns.
There is a solution suggested over the internet:

```
{Binding DataContext.IsColumnVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyControl}}}
```

IsColumnVisible property is of type System.Windows.Visibility. Such solution works for other properties like DataGridTextColumn.Binding, but doesn't for DataGridTextColumn.Visibility!
Is there solution for Visibility?

EDIT: I finally adopted the following solution:
[Bind datagrid column visibility MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711275/bind-datagrid-column-visibility-mvvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid-columns are abstract objects, you cannot target them using `ElementName` (lacking [namescope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189026.aspx)) or `RelativeSource` (not in the visual tree).

Additionally DataGrid-columns  **have no `DataContext`**...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But is there not too complex way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: @user835103: Well, as columns do not have a DataContext, what is the DataContext you try to target? The item's or the `DataGrid`'s?

Comment: The DataGrid's. Sorry for delay, I didn't have access to my SA account.

Comment: @user835103: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6858917/546730) of mine which should be easily adapted to your situation (move things into `DataGrid.Resources` and target the `DataGrid` and not the `Window`)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot use x:Reference because target .NET Framework 3.5. I finally adopted the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711275/bind-datagrid-column-visibility-mvvm.

Comment: @user835103: That of course is an alternative which i would have suggested as well given the circumstances. I prefer the *x:Reference* method where usable, seems a lot cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BooleanToVisibilityConverter to convert the Parent's Visibility property to a Boolean value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Comment: I don't need BooleanToVisibilityConverter here. ViewModel.IsColumnVisible and DataGridTextColumn.Visibility are both of type System.Windows.Visibility. Actually I temporarily changed ViewModel.IsColumnVisible type from bool to Visibility to get rid of converters for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `Visibility` property of your column to a property of your view model.
See [the following SA question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983272/silverlight-datagridtextcolumn-binding-visibility).

Another thing is: use the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) class. It's not good your view model exposes a property of a type (`Visibility`) that is closely tied to the view. This introduces a coupling between your view and your view model that should be avoided.

Exposes a `bool`, then let the view adapts itself to its view model using the converter.